# ionic2 - Google maps not working in Browser

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Its code below that I use to show map in my page.

1. ts file

   ```
   import {
      GoogleMaps,
      GoogleMap,
      GoogleMapsEvent,
      LatLng,
      CameraPosition,
      MarkerOptions,
      Marker
   } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

   export class MapPage {

    constructor(private googleMaps: GoogleMaps){}

     ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.loadMap();
     }

     loadMap() {
       let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
       let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);
       map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
               console.log('Map is ready!');
       });  
     }
   }
   ```
2. Html code block

   ```
   <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
   ```

Comment: And why it doesn't work? Please add all the relevant information about the error, otherwise we wouldn't be able to help you :(

Comment: no error in console, only blank screen appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `Google Maps` from Ionic Native, it won't work on the browser. `Ionic Native`/`Cordova plugins` work only in a simulator / real device **only**

Comment: thanks, the issue has been resolved, if somthing turns up later , i'll seek u for help

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Sure, feel free to edit the question or create a new one if you need help.